# Which better in MVC is to begin from empty project or Internet Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a system for management, which I'll build with MVC framework, I see some tutorial they begin from *Internet Application* but some programmer advise me to begin from scratch. Can anyone help me to choose which one is better ?

Note: I don't have enough time.

Comment: Define "better".  The two approaches are *different* in some measurable ways, but "better" is entirely subjective and based on the needs of what you're trying to accomplish.  Note: None of us have enough time, it's part of being mortal.

Comment: I mean if I start from internet application. Will I face difficult problems, because I am new in asp.net and MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new to the topic of C# MVC i recomend, you use a given Project Template. This way you have some guidance and you can adopt.